# URL folder system Django Python

Tags: python, django, url, directory

How is it possible to move through the folders using url like in Dropbox?

Example: I have an url to a file "site_name/home/path1/path2/file", how can I take the "path1/path2/file" as parameter from url in Django?

Or is the only way to use GET parameters as PATH to file "site_name/home?path=path1/path2/file"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using django 2.0+:

```
re_path(r'^.*', some_view)
```

Otherwise:

```
url(r'^.*', some_view)
```

You should put this after all other urls otherwise they'll stop working because this pattern matches every url.

And then you get the path in your view:

```
def some_view(request):
    full_path = request.path

    split_path = full_path.split('/')

    # If you have slash at the end of the url, you should pick the second last item.
    if len(split_path[-1] < 1:
        file = split_path[-2]
        folders = split_path[2:len(split_path)-2]
    else:
        file = split_path[-1]
        folders = split_path[2:len(split_path)-1]
```

For a path like `site.com/home/path1/path2/path3/file/` you'll get this if you print `folders`:

```
['path1', 'path2', 'path3']
```

Comment: Oh, thank you for the help! It's possible to create DB model (File, Folder, User) and save files url and then navigate like this?

Comment: Yes but if you're going to use db for folders then just add slug for them so you can find them easier.